# XML Schema reference

Tags: java, spring, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I have two XML Schemas. First (`A.xsd`) is located in a library jar file (`mylib.jar`) and the second one (`B.xsd`) is in my project.

I want to import `A.xsd` into the `B.xsd` and validate incoming XML via `Jaxb2Marshaller` embedded validator.

However I'm unable to make it work properly: it seems that inner XML validator of `Jaxb2Marshaller` does not understand references to files in jar-files (I just want to write something like `<xs:import namespace="http://my/schema.xsd" schemaLocation="classpath:schema.xsd">`).

How it could be fixed? How could library schema be referenced from a project schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out my answer to a previous question on how a ResourceResolver can be used to solve this problem:

- [JAXB SchemaFactory source order must follow import order between schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558333/jaxb-schemafactory-source-order-must-follow-import-order-between-schemas/3558845#3558845)

Your implementation of LSResourceResolver will handle loading the schema from the classpath and converting it to the appropriate result.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure your own resolver. Nothing in jaxb will use classpath:.

There is a JAXB sample which shows this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

classpath: is not a valid url for schema location. You will have to use [XML catalogs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/catalog.html#ctrlresolver) to load schemas from jars.