# referencing/including xsd files in a jar

Tags: java, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I want to add an xsd file to our project that relies on types defined in another xsd that is in a jar. We use jaxb to generate Java classes from the xsds.
How do i refer to SchemaContainingFooTypeIsInaJAR.xsd so that 'FooType' resolves correctly and the proper Java classes get generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="SchemaContainingFooTypeIsInaJAR.xsd"/>
<xs:complexType name="FooMoreType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="FooType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="something" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                            something something
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in these features:

- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-CompilingaschemafromaMavenartifact
- http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Usingcatalogs

In short, you can write a catalog file which would point to your schema in a JAR file:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "some/url/a.xsd" "maven:org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-tests-episodes-a!/a.xsd"
```

DISCLAIMER: I am the principal dev of maven-jaxb2-plugin.

Comment: Great stuff. In the second document, the link under "See this section in the JAXB guide" is broken.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Thanks, fixed. Here's this link: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Fixing_broken_references_in_schema.html

Comment: current link is https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-fixing-broken-references-in-schema

Answer (score 0):

See [XML Schema reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979053/xml-schema-reference) and [JAXB SchemaFactory source order must follow import order between schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558333/jaxb-schemafactory-source-order-must-follow-import-order-between-schemas/3558845#3558845)

The consensus appears to be:  you need to supply your own resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line:

`<xs:include schemaLocation="SchemaContainingFooTypeIsInaJAR.xsd"/>`

with

`<xs:include schemaLocation="jar:file:///path/to/jar/thing.jar!/path/inside/jar/to/file.xsd"/>`