# How to control JAXB in-memory schema generation ordering/sequence?

Tags: java, validation, jaxb, schema, unmarshalling

I've got 3 xsd files that depend on each other to build my element definitions.  Each xsd file has its own namespace.  When I generate my classes using JAXB xjc, I get 3 corresponding packages.  So far so good.

My problem comes when I want to do schema validation with the unmarshaller.  In order to avoid having to read in the xsd files, I generate the schemas on the fly from the class in question being unmarshalled.  However, since the class depends on objects from 2 other packages, it is unable to generate the schemas unless I specify all 3 packages.  Already, that isn't a very practical solution, as it requires me to know ahead of time the object hierarchy/dependency tree, and specify the package list accordingly.

My bigger problem comes when I try to create a new schema from the 3 generated schemas using the SchemaFactory (SchemaFactory.newSchema(Source[])).  Apparently, the order in which the schemas are provided to the schema factory is critical for it to resolve dependencies.  If the first schema in the array depends on a type definition from the last element in the array, I get a resolve error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ns1:InCalculationDataType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

If I modify the order, and put the 3rd schema first, it succeeds without error.

This makes it nearly impossible to write a method fairly generic, but rather have to code for each XSD case individually.

Is there anything I can do to alleviate this problem?  Is there some way to force the SchemaFactory to read everything first and only then generate its errors if it finds any?  I know you can create an ErrorHandler, however the JavaDocs indicate that if it throws a Fatal error, any further processing is unreliable.

**EDIT**

Just for my own peace of mind, I tried to create an error handler which ignored non-fatal errors (just logged them), however the generated schema was unreliable and was unable to properly validate xml errors.  Consequently, it had no value to me.

**END EDIT**

Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: I remember in my experience I had a case when the order of schemas in `SchemaFactory.newSchema()` did matter. And if remember correctly that was exactly what you got: once schema was depending on the other. But if you want to generate schemas on the fly, you know the dependency between them?

Comment: Yes, I do know their dependencies, but given that there are several different xsds that I want to generate on the fly, I was hoping to use a generic piece of code that instantiated the JAXBContext from the required class/pkg and generated the schema based on its needs.  However, if I need to code dependencies manually, then each XSD generation has to be coded independently, which is somewhat of an ugly solution, given that I have several such XSD/Objects to generate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much searching, I finally found the answer.  Hopefully this will help someone else.  There are already other threads on StackOverflow relating to this issue, but without knowing the proper keywords, I wasn't finding the responses.

The solution is to use an LSResourceResolver for the schema factory.  ie:

```
schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new LSResourceResolver(){})
```

where LSResourceResolver() is responsible for returning the include/import resource that is required by the XSD.

Searching for LSResourceResolver in SO found a few useful threads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3830649/827480, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342859/827480

I will try to post my own solution later when I have a little more time, but it closely follows what was already suggested in the two above links (mine is a little more simplified by using Strings instead of streams...).

**EDIT**

As promised, here is the snippet of code I ended up with:

```
        // get the schemas used by this class
        final Map<String, String> schemas = new HashMap<String,String>();
        schemas.putAll(generateSchemas(jc));

        List<StreamSource> sources = new ArrayList<StreamSource>();
        for( String schema : schemas.values() )
            sources.add( new StreamSource( new ByteArrayInputStream(schema.getBytes())));

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI );
        sf.setResourceResolver(new LSResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            public LSInput resolveResource(String type, final String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI){
                logger.debug( "Need to resolve Resource: " + namespaceURI );
                return new LSInput(){
                    @Override
                    public String getStringData() {
                        // return the schema if found
                        if( schemas.containsKey(namespaceURI)){
                            if( logger.isTraceEnabled())
                                logger.trace("resourceResolver: Resolving schema for namespace: " + namespaceURI + schemas.get(namespaceURI) );
                            return schemas.get(namespaceURI);
                        }
                        else
                            return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public Reader getCharacterStream() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setCharacterStream(Reader paramReader) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public InputStream getByteStream() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setByteStream(InputStream paramInputStream) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setStringData(String paramString) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getSystemId() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setSystemId(String paramString) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getPublicId() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setPublicId(String paramString) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getBaseURI() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setBaseURI(String paramString) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public String getEncoding() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setEncoding(String paramString) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean getCertifiedText() {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void setCertifiedText(boolean paramBoolean) {
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        // validate the schema
        u.setSchema(sf.newSchema(sources.toArray(new StreamSource[]{})));
```

and method generateSchemas(jc):

```
private Map<String, String> generateSchemas (JAXBContext jaxbContext) throws JAXBException{
    // generate the schemas
    final Map<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> schemaStreams = new LinkedHashMap<String,ByteArrayOutputStream>();

    try {
        jaxbContext.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver(){
            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                logger.debug( "GenerateSchemas: adding namespace: " + namespaceUri);
                schemaStreams.put(namespaceUri, out);
                StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
                streamResult.setSystemId("");
                return streamResult;
            }});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // no IO being performed.  Can safely ignore any IO exception.
    }

    // convert to a list of string
    Map<String,String> schemas = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    for( Map.Entry<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> entry : schemaStreams.entrySet() ){
        String schema = entry.getValue().toString();
        String namespace = entry.getKey();
        schemas.put(namespace, schema);
    }

    // done
    return schemas;
}
```

**END EDIT**

I hope this can help someone else in the future.

Thanks,

Eric